# Unable to execute Code on Databricks Community Edition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I am training on Event Hubs with Databricks on my Databricks Community Edition. I need to run the following code/Notebook, however I get the error message:

```
NoSuchElementException: head of empty list
```

However, when I run the same code/Notebook on my Azure Databricks the code run successfully. Does anyone clues why this won't run on Databricks Community, whereas the code runs without any issues on Azure Databricks?

```scala
%scala
val tags = com.databricks.logging.AttributionContext.current.tags

//*******************************************
// GET VERSION OF APACHE SPARK
//*******************************************

// Get the version of spark
val Array(sparkMajorVersion, sparkMinorVersion, _) = spark.version.split("""\.""")

// Set the major and minor versions
spark.conf.set("com.databricks.training.spark.major-version", sparkMajorVersion)
spark.conf.set("com.databricks.training.spark.minor-version", sparkMinorVersion)

//*******************************************
// GET VERSION OF DATABRICKS RUNTIME
//*******************************************

// Get the version of the Databricks Runtime
val runtimeVersion = tags.collect(
  { case (t, v) if t.name == "sparkVersion" => v }).head
val runtimeVersions = runtimeVersion.split("""-""")
val (dbrVersion, scalaVersion) = if (runtimeVersions.size == 3) {
  val Array(dbrVersion, _, scalaVersion) = runtimeVersions
  (dbrVersion, scalaVersion.replace("scala", ""))
} else {
  val Array(dbrVersion, scalaVersion) = runtimeVersions
  (dbrVersion, scalaVersion.replace("scala", ""))
}
val Array(dbrMajorVersion, dbrMinorVersion, _) = dbrVersion.split("""\.""")

// Set the the major and minor versions
spark.conf.set("com.databricks.training.dbr.major-version", dbrMajorVersion)
spark.conf.set("com.databricks.training.dbr.minor-version", dbrMinorVersion)

//*******************************************
// GET USERNAME AND USERHOME
//*******************************************

// Get the user's name
val username = tags.getOrElse(com.databricks.logging.BaseTagDefinitions.TAG_USER,
  java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString.replace("-", ""))
val userhome = s"dbfs:/user/$username"

// Set the user's name and home directory
spark.conf.set("com.databricks.training.username", username)
spark.conf.set("com.databricks.training.userhome", userhome)

//**********************************
// VARIOUS UTILITY FUNCTIONS
//**********************************

def assertSparkVersion(expMajor:Int, expMinor:Int):Unit = {
  val major = spark.conf.get("com.databricks.training.spark.major-version")
  val minor = spark.conf.get("com.databricks.training.spark.minor-version")
  
  if ((major.toInt < expMajor) || (major.toInt == expMajor && minor.toInt < expMinor))
    throw new Exception(s"This notebook must be ran on Spark version $expMajor.$expMinor or better, found Spark $major.$minor")
}

def assertDbrVersion(expMajor:Int, expMinor:Int):Unit = {
  val major = spark.conf.get("com.databricks.training.dbr.major-version")
  val minor = spark.conf.get("com.databricks.training.dbr.minor-version")
  
  if ((major.toInt < expMajor) || (major.toInt == expMajor && minor.toInt < expMinor))
    throw new Exception(s"This notebook must be ran on Databricks Runtime (DBR) version $expMajor.$expMinor or better, found $major.$minor.")
}

//*******************************************
// CHECK FOR REQUIRED VERIONS OF SPARK & DBR
//*******************************************

assertDbrVersion(4, 0)
assertSparkVersion(2, 3)

displayHTML("Initialized module variables & functions...")
```

Comment: Well, you call `head` on a single line in your code, you could print the content of the `tags` variable in your notebook and see what it contains

Comment: Hi Alex, can you describe what you mean by 'call head'?

Comment: Here: `val runtimeVersion = tags.collect(
  { case (t, v) if t.name == "sparkVersion" => v }).head`